# Segmentation Fault when using strtok

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, substring, min, c-strings

I get segmentation fault when using `char *s` in main. If I use `char s[100]` or something like that everything is ok. Why is that? SIGSEGV appears when i call `find_short(char *s)` function on line with instruction `char *token = strtok(s, delim);`. This is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int find_short(char *s)
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    const char delim[2] = " ";
    char *token = strtok(s, delim);
    while(token != NULL) {
        int len = (int)strlen(token);
        if (min > len)
            min = len;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return min;
}
int main()
{
    char *s = "lel qwew dasdqew";
    printf("%d",find_short(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
char *s = "lel qwew dasdqew";
```

creates a pointer to a *constant* string in memory.
Because that string is constant, you are unable to change its contents.
The `strtok` function will try to modify the contents by inserting `\0` at the token-delimiter locations, and will fail because the string cannot be modified.

---

Changing the line to:

```
char s[] = "lel qwew dasdqew";
```

Now makes `s` an array of local data that you are free to change.  `strtok` will now work because it can change the array.

Comment: @MihalacheRares: If this answer (or any other answer) solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The main your mistake is that you selected a wrong function to do the task.:)

I will say about this below.

As for the current program then string literals in C though they do not have constant character array types are immutable. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. And the function `strtok` changes passed to it string inserting the terminating zero between sub-strings.

Instead of the function `strtok` you should use string functions `strspn` and `strcspn`. They do not change the passed argument. So using these functions you are able to process also string literals.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t find_short( const char *s )
{
    const char *delim= " \t";

    size_t shortest = 0;

    while ( *s )
    {
        s += strspn( s, delim );

        const char *p = s;

        s += strcspn( s, delim );

        size_t n = s - p;

        if ( shortest  == 0 || ( n && n  < shortest ) ) shortest = n;
    }

    return shortest;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "lel qwew dasdqew";

    printf( "%zu", find_short( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3
```